# Why do I get an endless loop using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, momentjs, infinite-loop

I got the following string-array:

cohortsDates =

```
[
  '2020-11', '2021-01',
  '2021-02', '2021-03',
  '2021-04', '2020-10',
  '2021-05', '2020-12',
  '2021-07'
]
```

Now I try to sort it that the dates are in an ascending order from 2020-10 to 2021-07 with this code:

```
cohortsDates.forEach((month) => {
      for(var i = 0; i < cohortsDates.length; i++ ) {
        if(moment(cohortsDates[i+1]) < moment(cohortsDates[i])) {
          var swap = cohortsDates[i]
          cohortsDates[i] = cohortsDates[i+1]
          cohortsDates[i+1] = swap
          
        }
      }

    })

    console.log(cohortsDates)
```

But all I get is an endless loop and the sorted array never prints out. Does somebody know, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When `i === cohortsDates.length-1` (i.e. you are looking at the last item in your for loop) you test:

```
if(moment(cohortsDates[i+1]) < moment(cohortsDates[i])) {
```

Where `cohortsDates[i+1]` will always be `undefined` and thus less than the previous value.

So you swap them and assign `cohortsDates[i]` to `cohortsDates[i+1]`.

This increases `cohortsDates.length` by 1 so the end condition of the `for` loop doesn't apply.

You now loop again and `cohortsDates[i+1]`  is still `undefined` so it goes infinite.

---

JS has a [built-in `sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to do this. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I think it may be surprising to some that if you have an array and assign a value to an index that is past the end of the array, that the _length_ property of the array automatically changes to be greater than the highest index in use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't exactly have the most efficient sorting algorithm. When sorting, you should use javascript's `array.sort`:

```js
cohortsDates.sort((a, b) => moment(a) < moment(b) ? -1 : 1);
```

The `sort` method will loop over the array and call the function you passed as an argument with two of the values as parameters. If the function returns a negative number, that means `a` is less than `b`, a positive number means `a` is greater than `b`.